# Dynamically adding and selecting a menuitem in XUL

Tags: javascript, xul, menuitem

I'm using a Javascript object containing a list of phone codes to generate a dropdown menu in XUL.  My object has this form:

```
var CountryCodes = {
  "Afghanistan":"+93",
  "Albania":"+355",
  "Algeria":"+213"
}
```

The code for populating the menupopup looks like this:

```
var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for( var country in CountryCodes ) {
  var this_country = document.createElementNS(XUL_NS,'menuitem');
  this_country.setAttribute( 'label', country );
  this_country.setAttribute( 'value', CountryCodes[ country ] );
  docfrag.appendChild( this_country );
}
$('countryCodePopup').appendChild( docfrag );
$('countryCode').setAttribute( 'selectedIndex', 0 );
```

and my XUL looks like this:

```
 <menulist id="countryCode">
    <menupopup id="countryCodePopup"></menupopup>
 </menulist>
```

However, when I run it on the page, the menuitem gets created properly, but the first element of the menu doesn't get selected.  I tried to set a selected attribute on one of the fields, but the result is the same.  What am I missing here?

Thanks!
Luka

Update:  As it turns out, I was setting selectedIndex incorrectly.  It should have been done like so:
         $('countryCode').selectedIndex = 10;

Comment: I really don't understand  your code(i'm sorry) but I've given the answer as per documentation in Firefox XUL website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 document.getElementById("countryCode").selectedIndex = 10;
```

For reference, please check this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Manipulating_Lists